# Theming Drupal 8 - Loop through all posted articles and print specific section

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to create my first Drupal 8 theme. On the frontpage, I want to list all articles with the title, summary, date posted, etc.

I more or less achieved this using views. Basically {{ page.content }} in twig, but found it to be really inflexible and I didn't really get the results that I wanted. What I want to do is just to iterate through all the articles and print each section of that article "manually". For instance:

```
{% for page in pages %}
  {{ page.content.title }}
  {{ page.content.datePosted }}
  {{ page.content.body }}
{% endfor %}
```

So that I can have more control of what is happening and not making a lot of configuration in the views module when deploying. What is the best soltuion to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use Views. Configure you view (filter by content type, etc.), you have a lot of parameters to achieve what you need.

Set the view to show "Content" and give it a view mode (you can use the default `teaser`, `full`, or create your own view mode). Then you can create a custom template for this :

```
node--xxxx--teaser.html.twig
```

In order to know how to name your custom template file, enable `Twig` Debugging in `sites/default/services.yml`. Set the debug variable to `true`. And clear cache. Then, you will see in source code the template name suggestion like this :

```
    <!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * node--1--full.html.twig
   * node--1.html.twig
   x node--oeuvre--full.html.twig
   * node--oeuvre.html.twig
   * node--full.html.twig
   * node.html.twig
   -->
```

In your twig, you can do that kind of templating :

```
<a href="{{ url }}">{{ content.my_field_image[0] }}</a>

<h2><a href="{{ url }}">{{ node.title.value }}</a></h2>

<p>{{ content.body }}</p>
```